# Why fs.readFileSync encode single quote inside script tag to &quot;?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to get the content of an HTML file on my server using fs.readFileSync. But the string returned was encoded. Strangely fs.readFileSync only encode these 3 characters which resides inside script tag:

```
& => &amp;
' => &quot; (single quote)
" => &quot; (double quote)
```

Below is my read file code:

```
var content = fs.readFileSync("./path/to/file.htm", 'utf-8');
```

How can I get the raw content of my html file?

Comment: Isn't `&amp` and `&quot` the way to encode `&` and `'/"` in html?

Comment: Yeah, that's what fs.readFileSync returned when reading my .htm file. Only the javascript (inside the script tag) though, the html itself is not encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it's my mistake. Actually `fs.readFileSync` is not the problem. After I get the content from, I input the content to cheerio and load the content again from cheerio. Here's the code.

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var content = fs.readFileSync("./path/to/file.htm", 'utf-8');
var $ = cheerio.load(content);
```

console.log($.html()); // this will return HTML with encoded inline javascript